# RandomizedSearchCV Takes Long Time to Finish

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to do hyperparameter tuning using `RandomizedSearchCV()` where I have 6244 rows of data to be processed. At first, I used `GridSearchCV()` with 11 different estimators but it took so long and I gave up waiting for the result then changed `GridSearchCV()` into `RandomizedSearchCV()` and I also reduced the estimators from 11 to 6. However it still takes too long to get the results. Is there any other way to reduce the processing time?

Anyway besides using `MLPClassifier()` I also tried to run the same code on `GaussianNB()` and `KNeighborsClassifiers()` but those `base_estimators` only need approximately 30 seconds to run, when `MLPClassifier()` needs more than 2 hours to run and I even haven't get the result.

```
#Tuning bagging here

distributions = dict(n_estimators = [10,20,50,100,150,200])
bagging_nb = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=MLPClassifier(max_iter=10000), n_jobs=-1)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=fold, random_state=seed, shuffle=True)
grid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=bagging_nb, param_distributions=distributions, scoring=scoring, cv=kfold)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Best %f using %s' % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip (means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's not surprising that neural networks should take longer to train than the other models you've listed (although the default parameters are fairly small).  Do you really want to bag NN's?  Can you reduce the number of folds, or the maximum number of bagging estimators?  RandomizedSearchCV won't help over the grid search here: the default `n_iter` is 10, which is already larger than your grid.